# Understanding Linked List Hash Table Implementation

Tags: c, hash

```
/* a bucket is a linked list, each of whose entries contains a string and its hash */

typedef struct bucket bucket;
struct bucket {
  char *string;
  unsigned long int hash;
  bucket *next;
};
/* By convention, the empty bucket is NULL. */

typedef struct hash_table htbl;
struct hash_table {
  unsigned long int(*hash)(char*);
  bucket **buckets; /* an array of buckets */
  unsigned int n_buckets;
};
```

I am trying to understand the hash_table struct. Specifically what is the purpose and use of `unsigned long int(*hash)(char*);`? I feel like I can implement a hash table without it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The hash function can always be hardcoded and then you don't need the pointer.

Comment: Presumably it's a pointer to a function that computes the hash value.

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful. What happens in the event of a hash-collision, the bucket, instead of being a pointer to a single `bucket` is used as a pointer to a list of `bucket` where "chaining" is used to create the list.

Comment: `unsigned long int(*hash)(char*);` just allows the user to specify a hash function of their choice. A generic hash function might not work if the inputs are highly skewed and the user might know the right hashing function.